# P/Invoke problems with basic CRT functions (i.e., putchar, puts)

Tags: c#, debugging, interop, pinvoke

I've noticed something very strange. I was trying to call the CRT function "putchar", and was unable to get it to work. So I double-checked that I wasn't missing something, and I copied the code directly from the P/Invoke tutorial on MSDN to see if it worked.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx

You'll notice that they import "puts".

So I tested the exact code copied from MSDN. It didn't work! So now I got frustrated. I've never had this problem before.

Then I just so happened to run WITHOUT debugging (hit ctrl+f5), and it worked! I tested other functions which output to the console too, and none of them work when debugging but all work when not debugging.

I then wrote a simple C dll which exports a function called "PrintChar(char c)". When I call that function from C#, it works even if I'm debugging or not, without any problems.

What is the deal with this?

Comment: a) what does "doesn't work" mean? b) what is PrintChar doing/using ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means exactly what it says; the function does not perform the task it is supposed to, which is to write to the console. It does still return a value, and does not crash the program; if it did, I would have made note of that. 

PrintChar(char c) { putchar(c); }

That's all it is! And it works debugging or not. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad example, using the C-Runtime Library DLL to call puts.  Keep reading the tutorial as there is good info there, but try making Win32 API calls instead.

Here is a better introduction to p/invoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

It's old, but the information is still good.

**Edited**

My explaination was wrong.

I went looking for a correct explaination and I discovered that the C-Runtime puts method and the .NET Framework Console.Write method differ in how they write to the console (Console.Write works where the p/invoke to puts does not). I thought maybe the answer was in there, so I whipped up this demonstration:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        int written;
        string outputString = "Hello, World!\r\n";
        byte[] outputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(outputString);

        //
        // This is the way the C-Runtime Library method puts does it

        IntPtr conOutHandle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        WriteConsole(conOutHandle, outputBytes, outputString.Length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);

        //
        // This is the way Console.Write does it

        IntPtr stdOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        WriteFile(stdOutputHandle, outputBytes, outputBytes.Length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);


        // Pause if running under debugger 
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WriteFile(IntPtr handle, [In] byte[] bytes, int numBytesToWrite, out int numBytesWritten, IntPtr mustBeZero);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, IntPtr securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsole(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, [In] byte[] lpBuffer, int nNumberOfCharsToWrite, out int lpNumberOfCharsWritten, IntPtr mustBeZero);

}
```

Both of those successfully output under the debugger, even with the hosting process enabled. So that is a dead end.

I wanted to share it in case it leads someone else to figuring out **why** it happens -- Hans?

Comment: I'm scrating my head over why they would pick that example and I'm just not coming up with a good guess. The C-Runtime Library defines a standardized interface to the operating system. The .NET Framework defines a [managed] interface to the operating system. The two things are competing over the same thing so to speak. What were they thinking?

Comment: I think they were just trying to show an example of how interoperation works, not give people a practical piece of code to use in commercial products.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio hosting process is capable of redirecting console output to the Output window.  How exactly it manages to do this is not documented at all, but it gets in the way here.  It intercepts the WriteFile() call that generates the output of puts().

Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".  On that same page, enabling unmanaged debugging also fixes the problem.

Comment: Any guesses as to why the hosting process gets in the way?

Comment: @Ter: not really.  There are two ways to do console output, WriteFile() to stdout and directly through WriteConsole().  The hosting process could intercept one of them but not the other.  It isn't a good explanation though, afaik the CRT and .NET both use WriteFile().  Another one is that the CRT has code that's debugger-aware.  But that's not what I saw happening when tracing puts().  I'll wave my hands at this, it isn't very important.

Comment: See my edit, it's definately not WriteFile/WriteConsole related and the two of them do use different methods. Important? Certainly not. Though I am curious myself.